# How to Observe for a date in Angular 11?

Tags: angular

I need to add a year to a dropdown on every Jan 1st. But I imagine the code would have to constantly watch for the time to change

Consider my code here (I'm using getMinutes to test it, because I'm not going to sit here until Jan 1st lol) How can I implement this in an Observable(I'm guessing) so that it fires on the next minute (or on the next year realistically)?

```
newyear: any;

//The dropdown is instantiated with these values already because these years exist with content
years:Array<Object> = [
  {value: 2021, year: 2021},
  {value: 2020, year: 2020},
  {value: 2019, year: 2019},
  {value: 2018, year: 2018},
  {value: 2017, year: 2017},
  {value: 2016, year: 2016},
  {value: 2015, year: 2015},
  {value: 2014, year: 2014},
  {value: 2013, year: 2013},
  {value: 2012, year: 2012}
];


// Populating the Years Dropdown
// To be called in ngOnInit()
addYear() {
  let today = new Date()
 
  //I'll be using this instead
  let year = today.getFullYear();       
  let nextyear = today.getFullYear() + 1

  // for testing
  let min = today.getMinutes();   
  let nextmin = today.getMinutes() + 1;

  console.log("Minutes", min)
  console.log("Next Minute", nextmin)

  if (min === nextmin) {
    console.log("Happy New Minute")
    ///// What will really happen is the object below gets added to the years array 
    //this.years.unshift(this.newyear)
    //this.newyear = {value: nextyear, year: nextyear}
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface yearInterface {
  value: number;
  year: number;
}


newyear: any;

//The dropdown is instantiated with these values already because these years exist with content
years:yearInterface[] = [
  {value: 2021, year: 2021},
  {value: 2020, year: 2020},
  {value: 2019, year: 2019},
  {value: 2018, year: 2018},
  {value: 2017, year: 2017},
  {value: 2016, year: 2016},
  {value: 2015, year: 2015},
  {value: 2014, year: 2014},
  {value: 2013, year: 2013},
  {value: 2012, year: 2012}
];

yearsSource = new BehaviorSubject<yearInterface[]>(years);
yearsItem$ = yearsSource.asObservable();


// Populating the Years Dropdown
// To be called in ngOnInit()
addYear() {
  let today = new Date()
 
  //I'll be using this instead
  let year = today.getFullYear();       
  let nextyear = today.getFullYear() + 1

  // for testing
  let min = today.getMinutes();   
  let nextmin = today.getMinutes() + 1;

  console.log("Minutes", min)
  console.log("Next Minute", nextmin)

  if (min === nextmin) {
    console.log("Happy New Minute")
    ///// What will really happen is the object below gets added to the years array 
    //this.years.unshift(this.newyear)
    //this.newyear = {value: nextyear, year: nextyear}
    this.setNewYear({value: nextyear, year: nextyear});
  }

}

setNewYear(data: yearInterface) {
    this.yearsSource.next(data);
}
```

Now, in the HTML, in the dropdown you have to use something like:
**"yearsItem$ | async"**

Comment: code is yelling at me on data. It says Argument of type 'yearInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'yearInterface[]'

Comment: Do you mean add yearsItem$ | async to the *ngFor in option? `<option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.value" yearsItem$ | async> {{year.year}} </option>`

Comment: Something like: <option *ngFor="let year of yearsItem$ | async" [value]="year.value" > {{year.year}} </option>

Comment: the data is still throwing that error anyway. It doesn't compile

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be of more help. I hope someone with more knowledge will help you!